# IntelliJ IDEA always updating indices

Tags: intellij-idea

Version 2018.2   182.3684.101

every 2 sec.   again and again.
other project not like this.

I have to tr `fild->Invalidate Caches / Restart.`
no use.

What can I do now?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please try https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2018.2+EAP. See if disabling Android plug-in helps (http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html). Please report such bugs directly at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA in the future.

Comment: @CrazyCoder It works,unclick Android Support could solve this problem.thx~

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known issue specific to Android support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196167).

The issue is already addressed in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.1 version.